# scrapy script CannotListenError

Tags: python, scrapy, attributeerror

Good day, folks.

I have a simple parser based on scrapy framework. Here is the core code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import sys, os, logging
from utils import append_project_to_python_path, load_spiders
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
append_project_to_python_path()
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'delta_parser.settings'             #add django settings to the project
os.environ.setdefault('SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'scrapy_parser.settings')  #add path to scrapy settings to the project

# Settings for logging
configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
logging.basicConfig(
    filename = PATH + '/output/delta_scraper.log',
    filemode = 'w+b',
    format = '%(asctime)s [%(name)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
)

# Scrapy settings and spiders
settings = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
spiders = load_spiders()
map(process.crawl, spiders)      # attachs spiders to the crawling process

# Commented block for testing chosen spiders from this script
#from scrapy_parser.spiders.company_revsite_spider import CompanyRevsiteSpider
#process.crawl(CompanyRevsiteSpider)

process.start() # the script will block here until all crawling jobs are finished
```

It loads ~30 spider classes from spiders in spiders folder, attaches them to a crawling process and does the scraping work writing items to a DB using middleware in scrapy settings. This simple scheme has been working perfectly for some time but now I'm getting errors like **CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on 127.0.0.1:6073: [Errno 98] Address already in use** and **AttributeError: TelnetConsole instance has no attribute 'port'**.

I didn't add spiders or change settings recently. There is no program that uses 127.0.0.1:6073 before running the script. Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT**:

1. scrapy 1.0.3, twisted 15.4.0
2. Log starts with (I don't think that the log always started with initializing all spiders at the same time, actually I'd say they were initialized one by one while scraping in the past):

> ... (everything is ok)
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,539 [scrapy.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6072
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,556 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState, AutoThrottle
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,559 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,560 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,561 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: ProcessItemFields, CsvExportPipeline, DBExportPipeline
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,562 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,563 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,574 [scrapy.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6073
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,623 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on
>   signal handler: >
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/big-brother/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
>   result = f(*args, **kw)
>   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/big-brother/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/xlib/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 57, in robustApply
>   return receiver(*arguments, **named)
>   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/big-brother/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/telnet.py", line 56, in start_listening
>   self.port = listen_tcp(self.portrange, self.host, self)
>   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/big-brother/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/reactor.py", line 14, in listen_tcp
>   return reactor.listenTCP(x, factory, interface=host)
>   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/big-brother/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 478, in listenTCP
>   p.startListening()
>   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/big-brother/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 984, in startListening
>   raise CannotListenError(self.interface, self.port, le) CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on 127.0.0.1:6073: [Errno 98] Address already in use. 
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,642 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState, AutoThrottle
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,645 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,647 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,648 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: ProcessItemFields, CsvExportPipeline, DBExportPipeline
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,649 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,650 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
>   2016-04-11 06:20:04,665 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: >
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/big-brother/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
>   result = f(*args, **kw)
>   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/big-brother/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/xlib/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 57, in robustApply
>   return receiver(*arguments, **named)
>   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/big-brother/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/telnet.py", line 56, in start_listening
>   self.port = listen_tcp(self.portrange, self.host, self)
>   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/big-brother/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/reactor.py", line 14, in listen_tcp
>   return reactor.listenTCP(x, factory, interface=host)
>   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/big-brother/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 478, in listenTCP
>   p.startListening()
>   File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/big-brother/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 984, in startListening
>   raise CannotListenError(self.interface, self.port, le) CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on 127.0.0.1:6073: [Errno 98] Address already in use.
>   ... (more errors like the one above)
>   ... (spiders start to crawl pages returning items, i.e. the parser actually works after it, at least partially.)

Comment: Do you have a longer stacktrace? what version of scrapy are you using?

Comment: @paul Added versions and a traceback.

Comment: can you try 2 things: first, set `TELNETCONSOLE_PORT` setting to `None` (instead of default `[6023, 6073]`). If that doesn't work and if you don't need the telnet console, simply disable the extension altogether with setting `TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED=False`

Comment: @paul Thank you! It worked.

Comment: which "trick" did it?

Comment: @paul the first one, TELNETCONSOLE_PORT = None in scrapy settings. Thank you again!